# Can i access an edition pack I bought on my PSN account with a second account logged in?

Tags: ps4, psn, apex-legends

I bought octane edition on one account, can I access it on the other account?

Answer (score 1):

No. Purchases for Apex Legends count as Microtransactions and not DLC, so they can't be shared between accounts.